# Is there a way to partially copy over a Json dymamically using JsonPath?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have a Java application hosting a data retrieval API. I want to return different content to different callers. For example, for caller A, only 3 of all fields are available but for caller B, all fields should be returned.

Example: My DB stores "shop" data, including name, location and books sold in this shop. For the store locator web site, I only want to return the "name" and "location" field. For book browser client, I only want to return the "books" field, and for each book, only "category", "author" and "title" field; For the admin client, I want to return everything.

e.g.

```
{
    "shop": {
        "name": "Great Store",
        "location": {
            "country": "Canada",
            "province": "BC",
            "city": "Vancouver",
            "streetAddress": "123 ABC Ave"
        },
        "books": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95,
                "inStock": true
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99,
                "inStock": true
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99,
                "inStock": false
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99,
                "inStock": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm thinking of storing the configuration mapping between clients and the data to be accessed using JsonPath.

e.g.

```
"storeLocator": ["$.name", "$.location"]
"bookbrowser": ["$.books[*].category", "$.books[*].author"]
"admin": ["$"]
```

However, I don't see a good way to re-construct the data back as Json using the configuration to only fields specified in the JsonPath.

Does anyone have done this before? What approach does it take?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using a JSON-oriented database, like you mentioned in the example, then it would be more appropriate to design a query for each user role so that the database system could produce the result in the most efficient way without returning entire JSON object. If there is no such a database, then I think it has to be done "by hands" grafting each node to the result (using JsonPath). If your JSON documents store is just a file storage, then it might be also done by reading JSON streams, and picking relevant nodes only.

Comment: Are you asking for the JsonPath queries here, e.g. `$.shop.["name", "location"]` and `$.shop.books[*].["author", "category"]` ?

Comment: @wp78de I'm seeking a way that with the query results of the paths above, how I could re-construct the "shop" json with only the query results.